# Missing navigation bar after navigating from search controller

Tags: ios, swift

## Following scenario:

I have a master view with a navigation controller and table view. With a segue to the detail view. I added a search controller presented over the navigation bar analog to the [Apple UICatalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html). I added another segue from the search result controller to the detail view.

[image]

## Problem

When I select a row in the normale tableview the detail view contains a navigation bar and the behaviour is as expected.
When I perform a search and select a row in the result search controller the navigation bar is missing in the presented detail view. I know that the result view controller has now navigation bar.

## Question

What should I do to get the navigation bar from the standard navigation stack? I try to avoid to add the navigation bar manually to the detail view, because it is working when I came from the normale table view.

## Update

I added an additional segue from the main table view to the search table view.

[image]
When I invoke the search with: `showViewController(searchController, sender: tableView)` I get the navigation bar, but no search input. With `presentViewController(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)` I get the search view, but the navigation bar is gone in the detail view.

Answer (score 2):

I'm searching with another way, using main table view controller as `searchResultViewController`. There is an [awesome tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dz5IIzIeBa0) in Russian (but you can read code in English).

It helped me to set the search bar.

If you don't want to watch, just try

```
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
```

in `ViewDidLoad` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow your segues, you can see that there is no link between your navigation controller and the search controller. The search controller is not on a navigation stack at all, so when segueing to the results you don't get a bar. In order to be able to navigate back to your search controller, you will need to either segue to it from the normal tableview, or have a second navigation controller with the search controller as its root view, just like with your master view.

Comment: I tried both variants. Both have no visiible results. The navigation controller is nil.

Comment: Which navigation controller is nil? In your picture above your search controller is not attached to a navigation controller at all. In order to have all of these scenes on the same navigation stack, you'll have to do a push segue from your master to the search results, and then a push segue from the results to the detail.

Comment: I added a navigation controller to the results table view. After involving the search and selecting a result the navigation controller is nil. When connect the main navigation controller on the left side with the result table view controller, it seems working (in the IB is a navigation bar visible). But when I     run the app their is still no navigation bar in the detail view.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a solution. I ditched the results view controller and handle the results within the original table view controller. Before navigating to the detail view I hide the search bar if active:

```
    if searchController.active {
        searchController.searchBar.hidden = true
    }
```

When I go back to the main view controller I unhide the search bar again.

```
    if self.searchController.active {
        self.searchController.searchBar.hidden = false
    }
```

Comment: The above code didn't work for me, BUT I was able to get it to work by using one ViewController and declaring self.definesPresentationContext = true

Answer (score 1):

`presentViewController` presents the view controller outside of the navigation stack, if you want to put it inside your navigation stack you should use `pushViewController` like this :

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(searchController, animated: true)
```

then you can edit the navigation bar appearance if needed when searchController is the top view controller

Answer (score 0):

May be in some code or storyboard you are hiding navigation bar. Just try to put below line in your controller file, where you want to show navigation bar:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
```

Comment: Does not help. :-(  The navigation controller is nil.

Answer (score 0):

before pushing or presenting to next ViewController i added this line

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
```

and it worked for me